# PHP with PDO using sqlite3 keeps refreshing the page

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I just started working with sqlite3 and my page keeps refreshing on me and keeps inserting data into the database. If I comment out the insert execute command the page does not refresh. I am thinking that it may have to do with my connection to the database but I am not sure. Thanks in advance. Here is the complete code:

```
<?php

class create {

    function makeDB() {
        $pdo = new PDO("sqlite:db/SSDB");

        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $mainDB = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pass (
                    'rowID' INTEGER,
                    'username' CHAR(256) NOT NULL,
                    'pass' CHAR(256) NOT NULL,
                    'iv' CHAR(256) NOT NULL
                    )";

        $pdo->query($mainDB);
    }    
}

class connectDB {

    public function connect() {
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:db/SSDB");
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            return $dbh;
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }    
}

$connDb = new connectDB();
$conn = $connDb->connect();
$createDB = new create();
$createDB->makeDB();
$string = "hi1";
$salt = 'salt';
$encrypted_string = 'test';
$iv = 4;

$sql = "INSERT INTO pass VALUES(1,:encrypted,:salt,:iv)";

$sqlPrepare = $conn->prepare($sql);

$sqlPrepare->execute(array(':encrypted' => $encrypted_string, ':salt' => $salt,:iv'=> $iv));
```

Comment: How are you calling this script? Is it an AJAX server?

Comment: You have a typo at the end of your `execute` line, you are missing a `'`.

Comment: move that code INTO the class connectDB?

Comment: @jeroen True, but 99% of the time, they're typos. +1 nonetheless ;)

Comment: You're using quotes for your columns in your table creation code. Use backticks `\``

Comment: PHP runs completely on the server, it can't make the page refresh. That would probably be something to do with either some javascript you're using, a `<meta>` refresh you're issuing somewhere else, or something happening in your browser like an extension.

Comment: AT Barmar I am running this from Netbeans 8.0.1 with xampp on Apache.
AT Jeroen I fixed the typo.
AT Petro I don't know what that is
AT Fred I changed them to back ticks
AT Sammitch You see the whole code there is no JS or anything else other than what I posted

Answer (score 1):

As per your [**originally posted code/question**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26685091/1) that you edited and overwrote **without marking it as an edit**, should anyone see this and ask why the answer with the same ticks/quote fix:

Firstly, you're using (single) quotes for your columns in your table creation code.

Use backticks or remove the quotes.

```
$mainDB = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pass` (
            `rowID` INTEGER,
            `username` CHAR(256) NOT NULL,
            `pass` CHAR(256) NOT NULL,
            `iv` CHAR(256) NOT NULL
            )";
```

You're also missing a quote for `$salt,:iv'` => `$salt,':iv'`

<strike>Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened to find errors, which your original code should have thrown.</strike>

Or, `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` depending on the one you are using.

As for *"my page keeps refreshing on me"* - I can't see how your page would refresh. You will need to elaborate on that.

- There is no code in your posted question to support a page refresh, or redirection.

Comment: Looks like the refreshing is an issue with the Netbeans connector and chrome. I can't reproduce the refresh problem with firefox or running chrome without the connector. I want to do some more tests just to be sure. Isn't this calling it right after the connection or am I missing something
     `public function connect() {
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:db/SSDB");
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: @Kobaltic Using error exceptions helps to get the errors out into plain sight, which you should get. Now, you've edited and overwritten your question/code with what I've got in my answer without marking it as an "edit"; that's not how things are done here on Stack. People who will visit your question and compare your code to mine, stand at telling themselves *"there's nothing wrong with this, so why is there an answer with the same code?"* - and stand at downvoting my answer, which I plan on deleting for two reasons; because of what I wrote, and because it hasn't solved the problem; obviously.